# BeautifulSoup for extracting text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm not familiar to HTML and trying to extract the main body of a HTML. Firstly I have to filter all elements of HTML but remain text merely.
I receive some unexpected results as below when using method `get_text()` of BeautifulSoup.

```
var suffix = device.type === "pc" ? ".pc" : ".mobile";requirejs.config({
paths: {
    "F": "http://y0.ifengimg.com/base/origin/F-amd-1.2.0.min",
    "FM":  "http://y0.ifengimg.com/commonpage/1130/F-amd-mobile-1.1.0.min",
    "debug": "http://y0.ifengimg.com/commonpage/1130/F-amd-mobile-1.1.0.min",
```

Of course the text is included, but I don't want the function or other elements of HTML. After checking the code of HTML, it seems that these kinds of functions or scripts are between 2 elements `<script>` and `</script>`

I wonder whether I should use `re` module or `BeautifulSoup` can deal with my problem.

Have already done via method `extract()`...
But received another error. That looks like...
 `<img src***="1"/>`

Still it remains in `soup.get_text()`. Don't know why it, as a tag, isn't extracted. Surely I can remove it manually, but that seems not elegant for a programmer.

Comment: Hmm...got that problem before, removed them via text editor manually...However, what's your HTML file looks like?

Comment: So what do you mean about that `<img src***="1"/>`?

Comment: By rights, it should be removed by get_text(). But why it still remains.....@KevinGuan

Comment: Well, I didn't check how does `get_text` work, so I also don't know. Can you give us your HTML file?

Comment: Well, it works...That's something wrong with my HTML file and now gets removed. Anyway, really appreciate!

Comment: Oh, that's fine. Happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...looks like we can simply extract them (remove them from the BeautifulSoup Object, your HTML file):

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>Hello</p><script>console.log("A test!")</script>')
>>> soup.get_text()
'Helloconsole.log("A test!")'

>>> soup
<p>Hello</p><script>console.log("A test!")</script>

>>> soup.find('script')
<script>console.log("A test!")</script>

>>> soup.find('script').extract()
<script>console.log("A test!")</script>

>>> soup
<p>Hello</p>

>>> soup.get_text()
'Hello'
>>>
```

However if you have more `script` tags in your HTML file, use `soup.find_all()` instead like this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('script'):
    tag.extract()

print(soup.get_text())
```